# How to convert string?

Tags: android, service, notifications

I'm trying to get the data from service and pass it to notification.But when I run it in real devices, it just shows "has sent you a friend request" in notification, the data disappeared.Then I found the problem in logcat and the output is shown as following:

Logcat output:

```
   11-19 23:12:18.344: D/dataServices1(17701): admin*admin*
   11-19 23:12:18.344: D/dataServices2(17701): [Ljava.lang.String;@40d9f0d8
   11-19 23:12:18.344: D/dataServices3(17701): nulladmin,admin,
   11-19 23:12:18.344: D/dataServices3(17701): ,
```

admin*admin* < it has sent two data here.

So my problem is how to convert it to "admin" from "[Ljava.lang.String;@40da8e78" and Why it just shown "[Ljava.lang.String;@40da8e78" but not twice ? Like [Ljava.lang.String;@40da8e78 [Ljava.lang.String;@40da8e78...and why the "str"(dataServices3) output shown as like this?

Here is the code:

```
   String datapassed; 
   String str = "";
   String[] data;
   int dlength;

   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    datapassed = intent.getStringExtra("DATAPASSED");
    if(datapassed.length()>0){
    //update from here
        data = datapassed.split("[*]");
        dlength = data.length;

        for(int i=0;i<dlength;i++){
            if(i==dlength-1){
                str += String.valueOf(data[i]);                 
            }else{
                str += String.valueOf(data[i]) + ",";
            }
            Log.d("dataServices3",str);
            displayNotification();

        }
            str = "";
        Log.d("dataServices1",datapassed);
        Log.d("dataServices2",data.toString());
     //to here
    }
    }
    };

    protected void displayNotification(){
        Intent i = new Intent(this,NotificationView.class);
        i.putExtra("notification", notification);

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);

        NotificationManager mnotis =(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notis = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Reminder:You have " + dlength + " new friend request",System.currentTimeMillis());
        notis.setLatestEventInfo(this,"Friend Request", str + "has sent you a friend request",pi);
        notis.vibrate = new long[]{100,250,100,500};
        mnotis.notify(0, notis);
    }
```

Here is its logcat error output after runs it:

```
 11-19 23:28:46.388: E/ExternalAccountType(11253): Unsupported attribute readOnly
 11-19 23:28:46.648: E/ExternalAccountType(11253): Unsupported attribute readOnly
 11-19 23:28:57.218: E/MediaProvider(19282): invalid album art, error creating album thumb file
```

Comment: I am not sure, but try to replace String.valueOf(data[i]) to data[i]

Comment: It's printing that because ***data*** is a String[] not a String
On the other hand, do you really want to send one notification per piece of data ?
Or are you trying to construct one notification appending the different parts of the data

Comment: Jevgeni Smirnov : Sorry, it doesn't work for me.But thanks..

Comment: Robert Estivill : yup, I want to construct one notification appending the different parts of the data.

Comment: there are something different for the code and output:
I have add "dlength = data.length;" into code and modify "str = String.valueOf(data[i]);" becomes "str += String.valueOf(data[i]) + ",";".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I did not get it right, you have an object in the array and want to convert to to it is typed class in this case it is `admin`. If you did not keep in the array as string `array[0] = obj.toString()` does that you can cast your object as below.

```
admin adminFromData = null;
if (obj.getClass().isInstance(admin.class)) 
{
    admin = (admin)obj;
}
 //what ever you want with the admin object.
```

Comment: Thanks, my problem is solved just now. actually i correct some php error and declare the initiate for str, then the problem solved.Later I update my post in order to be a reference for others.

Comment: The output shown in status bar is "Reminder:You have 2 new friend request" and shown in notification details set now is "admin,admin has sent you a friend request".
Thanks for your all concern..